# Comprobación compacta de ordenamiento de caracteres unicode gráficos

Tags: javascript

```js
var x=['',''];
console.log(x.sort());
```

¿hay una manera más compacta de mostrarlo?

Comment: ¿Con compacta te refieres a una liena?

Comment: Hola Emilio, si tu pregunta *"¿hay una manera más compacta de mostrarlo?"*  no es retorica y  lo que pretendes es un "codegolf" este no es el sitio para ello. Aqui resolvemos dudas  o problemas que tengas durante el desarrollo. No veo ningun problema en tu pregunta. Por favor, lee [ask] y [help/on-topic] para más info. El tema de CodeGolf no se ha tratado en [meta] asi que si lo consideras válido puedes proponer una discusión a ver qué opina el resto de usuarios.  Un saludo

Comment: Me parece que está claro lo que pregunto. Podría haber puesto alfa y beta en vez de huevo y gallina, pero un poco de humor no le hace mal a stackoverflow. A veces los bytes cuentan (por ejemplo en la nube que te pagan por cada byte transmitido, almacenado, etc). La respuesta 26 bytes muestra una respuesta útil. No sé lo que es codegolf, solo sé algo de javascript, typescript y postgres y trato de ayudar con mi conocimiento (tanto en SO en español como en SO en inglés). La pregunta es corta (no aburre), muestra mi intento, tiene una pregunta concreta, está etiquetada. *El humo no daña, ilustra*

Comment: hola Emilio, lo entiendo. Las publicaciones con humor son más entretenidas, si, pero no hay que olvidar la correcta formulacion de las preguntas en el sitio. Un usuario pregunta a que te refieres con compactar. Es algo que deberias explicar en la pregunta, de ahi el *no está claro*, además de añadir lo que has intentado hasta ahora. Es un requerimiento en todas las preguntas, sean amplias o breves, humoristicas o no. Se pide lo intentado para sobre eso poder ayudarte. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Y date cuenta que 2/3 respuestas no están respondiendo lo que se supone que pides.Un saludo!

Comment: y Codegolf, es un tipo de *challenge* de programación que consiste en obtener  el mismo resultado pero con el menor numero de caracteres. el sitio de esta red,  [codegolf.se] es chulisimo pero muy dificil hehhe

Comment: el humo no daña, ilustra. Y la consultoría se paga, no se burla. Mantengamos este lugar como un polo de ayuda. Para lo otro podemos intercambiar tarifas por interno >;(

Answer (score 6):

Para Unicode, la [gallina](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f414) fue primero, no el [huevo](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f95a).

Y en vez de compactar, hagamos más pruebas *¿habrá sido primero el gallo o la gallina*?:

```js
//: U+1F413 Unicode 6.0
//: U+1F414 Unicode 6.0
//: U+1F423 Unicode 6.0
//: U+1F95A Unicode 9.0

var x=["","","",""];
console.log(x.sort());
```

Para las entidades HTML también:

```
//&#129370;  huevo
//&#128020;  gallina
$arr=array('&#129370;','&#128020;');
asort($arr);
foreach ($arr as $item){    
    echo $item.PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```html
&#128020;
&#129370;
```

Answer (score 2):

26 bytes (?)

```js
alert(['',''].sort())
```

Comment: `alert(['',''])` :/